# Is there an existing MVC HtmlHelper like @Html.Label that generates a <span>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm wondering if I need to create a custom HtmlHelper to simply display a value as a span.

Currently I'm using:

```
@model string
@{
    var htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"]);
}
<span class="@htmlAttributes["class"]">@Model</string>
```

I'm just wondering if there already exists something like @Html.Label so I could do:

```
@model string
@Html.SomethingLikeSpan("", Model, @ViewData["htmlAttributes"])
```

Comment: why not just do `<span>@Model.Value</span>`. creating a helper just for span seems like overkill.

Comment: I am curious, why do you think you need to create an HtmlHelper for a span element?  What benefit are you going to receive from that?

Comment: I edited my question to show what I'm currently using, compared to what I'd like to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet, but you can extend the Helpers object with any tag combination you wish.

Add a class file named HtmlHelperExtensions.cs with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString Span(this HtmlHelper Helper, string Content, string Class = "")
        {
            string classstring = Class == "" ? "" : string.Format(" class=\"{0}\" ", Class);
            string htmlString = String.Format("<span{1}>{0}</span>", Content, classstring);
            return new HtmlString(htmlString);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your view, use the following to format anything with the new helper extension:

```
@using WebApplication1

@Html.Span("Test Content")

@Html.Span("Test with class", "btn btn-primary")
```

Comment: Thank you for going far beyond just saying "Not yet"

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is quite old but I'm going to post what I used to accomplish a very basic version of the @Html.Span and @Html.SpanFor helpers. I'll post for both .netcore and MVC5. I hope this helps people out!

MVC 5 implementation

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class HMTLHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Span(this HtmlHelper Helper, string Name, string Content, object HtmlAttributes)
    {
        var htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(HtmlAttributes);

        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("Span");
        tag.MergeAttribute("name", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(Name));
        tag.GenerateId(Name);
        tag.InnerHtml = Content;
        foreach(var i in htmlAttributes )
        {
            tag.MergeAttribute(i.Key, i.Value.ToString());
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString Span(this HtmlHelper Helper, string Name, string Content)
    {
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("Span");
        tag.MergeAttribute("name", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(Name));
        tag.GenerateId(Name);
        tag.InnerHtml = Content;
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SpanFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> Helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string Content, object HtmlAttributes)
    {
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, Helper.ViewData);
        return Span(Helper, name, metaData.Model as string, HtmlAttributes);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString SpanFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> Helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string Content)
    {
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, Helper.ViewData);
        return Span(Helper, name, metaData.Model as string);
    }
}
```

and here is the .netcore implementation

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal;
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlContent Span(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string Content, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("Span");
        tag.MergeAttribute("name", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(name,""));
        tag.GenerateId(name, "");
        tag.InnerHtml.Append(Content);
        var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        foreach (var i in attributes)
        {
            tag.MergeAttribute(i.Key, i.Value.ToString());
        }
        return tag;
    }

    public static IHtmlContent Span(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string Content)
    {
        TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("Span");
        tag.MergeAttribute("name", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(name, ""));
        tag.GenerateId(name, "");
        tag.InnerHtml.Append(Content);
        return tag;
    }

    public static IHtmlContent SpanFor<TModel, TProperty>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>> expression, string content, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var modelExplorer = ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData, htmlHelper.MetadataProvider);
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var metaData = modelExplorer.Metadata;
        return Span(htmlHelper, name, modelExplorer.Model as string, htmlAttributes);
    }

    public static IHtmlContent SpanFor<TModel, TProperty>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, string content)
    {
        var modelExplorer = ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData, htmlHelper.MetadataProvider);
        var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        var metaData = modelExplorer.Metadata;
        return Span(htmlHelper, name, modelExplorer.Model as string);
    }
}
```

I want to point out, these will work with html attributes only if used in this format.

```
@Html.Span("Test", "Testing Content", new { @class = "test-class", style = "text-align:right" }
@Html.SpanFor(x=>x.ModelProperty, Model.ModelProperty, new { @class = "test-class", style = "text-align:right" }
```

Comment: Great I just need this